# How do you write a javascript function that displays a Map in D3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Right now, I have this working iframe for a map.

```
    <div style=" position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 508px; width:300px;max-width:100%;overflow:hidden;height:200px;color:red;"><div id="my-map-display" style="height:100%; width:100%;max-width:100%;"><iframe style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=null,+null,+null&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU"></iframe>
```

I would like to initially have this hidden and have a function such that I can call and add and remove it on call. I am trying to write something like:

```
    var mapIsOn = false;
    showMap(_city, _state, _country){
        if(mapIsOn == false){
            svg.append("iframe")
            ... add the features listed above
            .attr("id","MAP")
        }else{
            svg.selectAll("#MAP").remove();
            mapIsOn = false;
        }
```

Is there any way to do it? I've seem that it is possible to create div's but so far with this, I am not having much luck. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: never post your keys online. Remove it

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to achieve that. This is probably the simplest method. Idea is to set display none and remove it when we want to show the map.

```css
.nodisplay {
    display : none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#my-map-display").toggleClass("nodisplay");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Toggle map</button>
 <div id="my-map-display" class="nodisplay" style="height:100%; width:100%;max-width:100%;"><iframe style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=null,+null,+null&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```